# oData navigation vs filtering

Tags: odata, odata-v4

When using a navigation:
http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Suppliers(1)/Products
or filtering: [http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=SupplierID eq 1](http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=SupplierID%20eq%201)

I will get exactly the same results so products belonging to the supplier "1". So when and why should I use navigation and when filtering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example of fitering is indeed something that can be achieved easier by using navigation.

Use navigation when you **know the key** of the element you are looking for (your first example) and use filtering when you want to get a subset of elements that match a certain criteria.
E.g. get all records with a reorder level > 20:

[http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Suppliers%281%29/Products?$filter=ReorderLevel gt 20](http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Suppliers%281%29/Products?$filter=ReorderLevel%20gt%2020)

Comment: Also note that the response structure is different. When you query an item, you will get a single object result, when you query a collection and use `$filter` to scope the results to a single row by _Key_,  the service should return an array with a single element.